# C++ VS 2017 Setting global variable -- Program works only using a breakpoint in debug

Tags: c++

My "lClick" global variable gets set to true successfully when I set a breakpoint where it should be set to true, but not if run otherwise. Please help!

In global.h:

```
#pragma once

extern bool lClick;
```

In global.cpp:

```
#include "global.h"

bool lClick = false;
```

In main.cpp:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        {
            int iPosX = LOWORD(lParam);
            int iPosY = HIWORD(lParam);
            lClick = true;
            break;
        }

        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            // draw bitmaps
            DrawAll(hdc);

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
```

In Scrabble.cpp:

```
void DrawArrow(HDC hdc, int x, int y)
{
    Draw("arrowrt_mask.bmp", hdc, 110, 150, 1);
    Draw("arrowrt.bmp", hdc, 110, 150, 2);
}

void DrawAll(HDC hdc)
{
    InitPaint(hdc);
    Draw("board.bmp", hdc, 10, 50);
    Draw("racks.bmp", hdc, 770, 10);
    Draw("textarea.bmp", hdc, TEXT_AREAX, TEXT_AREAY);

    // display arrow if player left clicked somewhere on the board
    if (lClick)
    {
        DrawArrow(hdc, 0, 0);
    }
```

The goal is to draw an arrow somewhere on the Scrabble board when the user left clicks.

Comment: Why do you need a global variable for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Painting only happens when it needs to.  You probably intended to repaint the screen on mouse clicks, but if so then you need to invalidate the window.

Assuming hwnd is your main window, add this as the last line of case WM_LBUTTONDOWN (before break):

```
 InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE);
```

Comment: Thank you!  That fixed it.  However, the whole screen flickers now before the arrow appears.  Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Yes, look at InvalidateRect in docs.  The "rect" = rectangle, it does not need to be the full client area.

Comment: Also, if you want to update 2 spots, like an old and new click location, you can call InvalidateRect twice with 2 small rectangles.  Windows gathers up and combines all invalid areas the next time it sends a paint event.